# Persist data in db2 LuW Docker Container

Tags: docker, db2, volume

I'm running a docker container of a db/2 luw image (custom image of a DB2ExpressC on RHEL). The container exposes the service to port 50000 and is available from the "outside". The user is db2inst1 and seems to be a standard username for the database. 
I start the container with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -itd -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=kvl -e DBNAME=BLA -p 50000:50000 -v db2luw:/home/db2inst1 db2:v11.1-7
```

When i look into the container there is a home-directory of the db2inst1 user wherein the db-instance places its data. I thought if i create a volume with the home-directory as mountpoint, it would cause my data to be persistet in it after a restart of the container.

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be? I cant find a wiki or useful documentation.

Comment: What kind of Db2 docker image? Is it a custom image or one provided by IBM? For IBM image, often there is "data" directory from where you configured and invoked it

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us the symptom! Then we can suggest the cause.  If `db2luw` in your command-line is a bind-mount (as documented on docker website) then anything the container writes to /home/db2inst1 (in the container) will persist to `db2luw` on the host.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to create the volume with the correct target (mount-point). The db2-image uses 
`/home/db2inst1/data`
as its data-directory.